# file created using pingendo is uploaded on server but its css is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, pingendo

i created a html page in pingendo using its drag and drop feature.
3 files were created `draft.html, draft.css, draft.less`.
I uploaded files on my website on `hostinger`.
But it only shows the html part and css is not loaded.
what changes should I make in pingendo files to make it work?

Comment: did you just put the three files in to  server ? or did you create a backend for it like php or django ?  I need clarity on it.

Comment: @Simplans all three are static pages

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking to the css file sored locally on your machine in your HTML?

IE: `<link href="C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\web\assets\draft.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Rather than directly going to the path of the CSS in relation to your HTML page?

IE `<link href="assets\draft.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

May I have a link to your site to take a look?